# Hide or Show Action Bar in Fragments Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar, hide, show

I have to know the best way to deal with hiding or show Action Bar in Fragments. I figured out that it, not the same as in Activity where I could apply the style in Manifest.
I have tried to apply the style in the Fragment XML file with no effect.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PreviewFragment"
    **style="@style/MyStyleHereNoActionBar"**>
</FrameLayout>
```

Another option that worked, but might be unstable is:

```
class PreviewFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

// hide action bar         (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()
// show action bar         (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.show()

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preview, container, false)
    }
```

and the last one adding one or both  methods :

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.hide()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.show()
    }
```

So I love to know what I could do better or another way of doing it. Or rather a right way to do it.

And second how to apply custom styles to Fragments the right way.

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't face any problem with this approach, `ActionBar` is part of the activity not fragments, so you can access it through its activity

Comment: FYI, you can use a `NoActionBar` theme, and then put a Toolbar view in the layouts of the fragments that need one. You can manage the Toolbar directly, or set it as the Activity's support action bar to manage it the traditional way. If you do that, null out the support action bar when leaving the fragment. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity#setSupportActionBar(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar)

Answer (score 1):

You are adding fragments inside an activity and the activity has action bar. So in the specific fragment where you want to show the action bar get the activity and show the activity, and hide it where you don't want to show.

Or if you want to use action bar inside a fragment then just add a linear layout to the top of the fragment with height `"?android:attr/actionBarSize"`. I think this should do the job.

Comment: I got that, about activity dictating how Fragments UI will look. Not making it easy to deal with changes.

Comment: I have never tried to with action bar. But in one project I wanted to animate action bar on fragment change. So I used just one activity and others only fragments and used a linear layout as action bar in the main activity. So when a fragment change happens it calls animateActionBar function and it worked just fine for me.